# Mongodb: How to update calculated field in atomic operation

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In an atomic update operation, I would like to (re)calculate a field in a document based on the updated values of other fields in the same document.
Example:

Documents have this structure:

```
{ _id: xxx, nrValues: 4, sumOfValues: 20, meanValue: 5 }
{ _id: yyy, nrValues: 3, sumOfValues: 12, meanValue: 4 }
```

The (indexed) meanValue field is needed for fast sort/find operations.

Now I would like to "add" new values to documents like in this pseudocode:

```
Documents.update( { _id: xxx },
                  { $inc: { nrValues: 1, sumOfValues: newValue },
                    $set: { meanValue: sumOfValues / nrValues } } );
```

Is there a way to find real code for this pseudocode?

*BTW: I know that I could use map/reduce/aggregation to sort/find the documents this way without having an actual meanValue field at all, but I do want this actual field in the document and in my (Meteor based) situation I cannot use map/reduce/aggregation.*

Comment: You can run any mongo queries in your meteor environment as long as you are on the server. If you want to invoke it on the client, create a method.

Comment: You cannot do this atomically in MongoDB as part of a basic query as you will need to do the math with the field values client-side and then update the document with the answer.